# Which is preferred to include third library's header files? #include "filename" or #include <filename>?

Tags: c

For some well-known third-party libraries, such as Boost, they are usually installed in specific paths on the system, while for other third-party libraries, they are typically fetched directly from a Git repository using CMake's FetchContent command and placed in a certain location within the current project directory. For these two cases, should one use #include  or #include "filename"

Comment: They're not going to be in the same directory as any of your source files, so there is no reason to use `#include "filename"`,

Comment: @user207421: The question is primarily about the difference between the `" "` and `< >` forms of the include directive, and OP likely means `filename` to include path components as appropriate. But even if they do not, `#include "filename"` does not mean the file must only be in the same directory as the source file being compiled. Per the C 2018 6.10.2 3, how the file is searched for is implementation-defined, and compilers commonly provide ways for the user to configure the locations to be searched.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that everything stored in your project source folder(s)/repo should be included as `"header.h"` and headers which aren't should be included with `<header.h>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard leaves it to C implementations to specify how files are searched for for `include` directives with the constraint that `#include "filename"` becomes `#include <filename>` if the initial search for the `#include "filename"` form fails.

However, it is conventional to use `#include <filename>` for headers provided by the C implementation, the operating system, and third-party headers provided by the system (such as those installed by the system administrator), and to use `#include "filename"` for headers that are part of a software project. For third-party files installed by the user, the choice is less clear. However, for third-party files installed in your project’s directory tree, the `#include "filename"` form is more appropriate.

Nonetheless, you could make either form work with suitable compiler switches.